# Bug in SO question list answered questions in SO shows as zero answered post

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I have noticed that the question which has accepted answer shows zero answers in list as i have attached a screenshot below
[image]

the first question link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309001/not-able-to-insert-the-string-has-apostrophe-into-sqlite-ios) which has a accepted answer but in image it don't have any.

The second question link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451793/setcollectionviewlayoutanimated-causing-debug-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-h) which has 4 answers but not accepted. but the tile in image shows 4 answers and the background color indicates as accepted but that question doesn't have accepted answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you have just run into the cached version (**4 hours old** question shown as having been asked 1 min ago - look at the dates), possibly by clicking "go back" button in your browser or "go forward" - in this case SO would show the cached version. Reload the page and everything is sorted.